Simpler proof of elements generating dense subgroup of $U(2)/U(1)$
I want to prove the following statement:

The matrices
$$
T := \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & e^{i\pi/4} 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad 
H := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\ 
1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
generate a dense subgroup of $U(2)\mathbin{/}U(1)$. That is, $\overline{\bigl\langle{TU(1), HU(1)}\bigr\rangle} = U(2) \mathbin{/} U(1)$.

This is a standard result relevant in quantum computing, where the usual proof goes about showing that $THTH$ and $HTHT$ correspond to rotations about different axes by irrational angles.
I was wondering whether one can prove this using properties of Lie groups. Specifically, we know that an arbitrarily small neighborhood of the neutral element will already generate the whole connected component. So if we can show that we can always approximate the elements near $e \in U(2) / U(1) \cong SO(3)$, then we are done.

I feel like finding a proof that doesn't boil down to a version of the usual one might be tricky. But I'm actually wondering about the 'we know' part of your question — does 'an arbitrarily small neighborhood of the identity will generate the whole connected component' actually imply that 'if we can show density in a neighborhood of the identity then we have density over the whole connected component'? It's 'intuitively obvious' but I'm having a hard time coming up with a compelling argument.

In the case of $SO(3)$ we know that the connected component can be 'tiled' with a finite number of (potentially overlapping) translates of any arbitrarily small neighborhood of the origin and so the proof goes through cleanly but it's not immediately clear to me that that's true in the general case.

@StevenStadnicki, "covered", for sure, but what do you intend by "tiled"? I don't see how an essential disjointness would hold... Please advise?

Sorry; 'tiled' is sloppy terminology there. Covered is more accurate. Thank you!

@StevenStadnicki Let $G$ be a connected Lie group and $U$ an open set containing the neutral element. Wlog assume $U$ is symmetric under inversion. Then $H = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U^n$ is an open subgroup of $G$. But then $G/H$ is a partition of $G$ into disjoint open sets, so $H=G$.

What you are aiming for is not at all simpler than the more standard proofs. One can call it a "technology-free" proof since it aims to avoid a basic fact about subgroups of $SO(3)$ (namely, if a subgroup is infinite and acts irreducibly then it is dense). In general, the rule of thumb is "the less technology you use, the harder your proof will be." This is not always true, but it is "typically" true.
